# VS Code search per tab (or independent search)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Imagine two opened tabs in VS Code, in the first one I have an xml file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <film actor="actor1" />
    <film actor="actor2" />
    <film actor="actor3" />
</xml>
```

I'm searching all the values of the `actor` attribute, so I'm searching for `actor=`.

In the second tab, I have, let say a text file with many information and the texts `actor1`, `actor2`, `actor3`.

In the first tab, each time a match is found (`actor=`) I copy the value (`actor1`, `actor2`, `actor3`) in the clipboard and I search for this value inside the second tab.

I find it, do what I need to do then I come back to the first tab where I press `F3` to search for the next value of the actor, but VS Code did not kept my initial search text, it is searching for the value that I searched in the second tab.

Is there a way to keep searches independent per tab?

Comment: You can open a new window instead of a new tab, then search is independent.

Comment: @Laurenz thank you for your answer but it is not very practical.